# Datatable.Select rows with same value on Column A and B

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to select rows from a datatable that have same values on both Column A and B. I know how to select rows based on an exact value on a column, but how do you do it in this case?

```
Dim Expression1 As String = "Column_A = Column_B"
Dim SelectedRows() = EleUsedDATUMtable.Select(Expression1)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with `Dim SelectedRows = [DataTable].Select("Column_A = Column_B")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In EleUsedDATUMtable.Rows
    If Row.Cells("Column_A").Value.ToString = Row.Cells("Column_B").Value.ToString Then
        Row.Selected = True
    End If
Next
```

Don't forget to change property `"Multiselect" to True` in your DataGrid

You can use `Row.Cells("Column_A").Value.ToString` or `Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString` (if your column A index is 0)

Comment: It looks like `EleUsedDATUMtable` is a DataTable, not a DataGridView (as the Tag on the question and also *I need to select rows from a datatable* imply).